# How to run cypress tests into Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline using vsts-ci.yml

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, cypress

I would like to setup and run my Cypress tests into `Azure DevOps` CI/CD pipeline. Any idea where to add the following file `vsts-ci.yml` in my Azure DevOps pipeline. We are using Docker Images for creating a container.  Could someone please advise on how to proceed further ? I was referring to the below link for details.

https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/vsts-ci.yml

Answer (score 0):

just add that file anywhere in the repo and use the UI wizard to create a build and target that yaml file to create a build

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav

you dont need to turn off yaml pipelines for that (as the article claims).

Comment: I will try that way and reply back to you

Comment: Getting error Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings. Could not find a pool with name Hosted Ubuntu 1604 (Hosted Ubuntu 1604).  I have choose the vsts-ci.yml as per the Cypress website tutorial and added the queue name `queue: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604 (Hosted Ubuntu 1604)'`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already figured this out this by now, but here you can find a very minimalistic project where I have setup Cypress to run on Azure DevOps.

**The Azure DevOps project** : https://dev.azure.com/Coutinhos/Cypress-POC/_build

**The code on GitHub** : https://github.com/binte/cypress-tutorial-build-todo-starter

For each of the chosen browsers, namely Chrome, Firefox and Edge, I do the following steps:

1. Install project dependencies
2. Verify if Cypress can be executed
3. Start the server using the `start-server-and-test` package, allowing the tests to be executed in the same task. This prevents the pipeline to halt while the server is running
4. Publish the test results, allowing these to be visualised in the pipeline run
5. Publish screenshots in case of failure